# Passing associative array to where caluse in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a table namely `objects`
and it has some test data.

```
id    name      type      brand      model      remark

1     abc       laptop    dell       2019       text
2     def       laptop    dell       2019       text
3     efg       laptop    dell       2018       text
4     xyz       laptop    asus       2019       text
```

I have an array like below because I want all laptops `where brand = dell AND model = 2019`:

```
$search_arr = array(["brand" => "dell"], ["model" => "2019"]);
```

In my query,

```
Objects::where(
    ["type", "laptop"],
    $search_arr
)->get();
```

> But, I get all rows (id => 1, 2, 3). How can I do that?

I have another functionality that searches separately either brand or model.

For that, I prepare the array:
`$search_arr = [["brand" => "dell"]];`
`$search_arr = [["model" => "2019"]];`

It works!!!

**edited**
I've spent on this all day long. Finally, I've reached on here.

As possible as I can, I don't want to change the array syntax style. I want to change only the query syntax if I have to.

Comment: Wait sorry but did you fix your problem? If so provide the solution as a awnser so other people who run into the same problem can find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your `type` to your search

```
$search_arr = [
  "brand" => "dell",
  "model" => "2019",
  "type" => 'laptop'
];
Objects::where($search_arr)->get();
```

or you could say

```
Objects::where('brand', '=', 'dell')
  ->where('model', '=', '2019')
  ->where('type', '=', 'laptop')
  ->get();
```

and that would be it

Comment: Your first approach makes me happy. It works! Thanks.